# How to pass a list of column names as variable in BigQuery without using "excute imemdiate"

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am using CTE query and I am coming up with many queries that do essentially the same function but only the column names are different. This is a simplfied example

```
WITH org_sales AS (
SELECT    'team_a' AS teamId, 'CA' AS state, 12.1 AS sales, 'code1' AS jobCode
UNION ALL    SELECT        'team_a','IL',13.1, 'code1'
UNION ALL    SELECT    'team_a','CT',5.1,'code1'
UNION ALL    SELECT        'team_a','FL',14.1,'code11'
UNION ALL    SELECT        'team_a','MA',10.3,'code11'
UNION ALL    SELECT        'team_b','AZ',8.1,'code2'
UNION ALL    SELECT    'team_b','MO',6.2,'code2'
UNION ALL    SELECT        'team_b','CA',7.3,'code2'
),
team_state_sales AS(
    SELECT 
        teamId,state,AVG(sales) sales_avg from org_sales
    GROUP BY
        teamId,state
),
team_jobCode_sales AS(
    SELECT 
        teamId,jobCode,AVG(sales) sales_avg from org_sales 
    GROUP BY
        teamId,jobCode
)
SELECT teamId,state,jobCode from org_sales
```

```
teamId  state   jobCode sales
team_a    CA    code1   12.1
team_a    IL    code1   13.1
team_a    CT    code1   5.1
team_a    FL    code11  14.1
team_a    MA    code11  10.3
team_b    AZ    code2   8.1
team_b    MO    code2   6.2
team_b    CA    code2   7.3
```

I was hoping to replace ['team_jobCode_sales','team_state_sales',...] with a general query that takes the column list for GROUP BY and SELECT as variabe (string) using **CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION** together with ***execute immediate*** however it does not work with CTE.

The psuedocode is something like that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION sales_avg(select_cols STRING,groupby_cols STRING)
AS
  SELECT select_cols,
          AVG(sales) sales_avg 
  FROM  
           org_sales
  GROUP BY
           group_cols
```

The only way I know that could be done is using *execute immediate*, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I feel what you are looking for is a stored procedure:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/procedures

It allows you to create programmatic way to take in variables and allow to plug into execute immediate statements easily.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mydataset.your_proc_name(select_cols STRING, group_by_cols STRING)

BEGIN 
....
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("your select query ",select_cols," from .... where ... group by ",group_by_cols );
...
END
```

You can do pretty advance stuff with stored procedures in bigquery so definitely worth looking at.

Comment: How does it work in the contect of CTE queries. In my example, inside "create procedure" I cannot access  "org_sales"

Comment: you can always make it a temp table within the proc like this:

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `YOUR_PROC_NAME`(IN select_cols STRING, IN group_by_cols STRING)
BEGIN 
  create temp table org_sales as 
    SELECT    'team_a' AS teamId, 'CA' AS state, 12.1 AS sales, 'code1' AS jobCode;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("select ",select_cols," from org_sales group by ",group_by_cols );
END;

Comment: though having temp tables is more ideal for readability; remember you can put pretty much any legal sql inside EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT so u can shove in entire query in there if u like and it will work if it comes to that.